# English dictionary SQL dump?

Tags: dictionary, database-dump

I'm looking for an open source, full english dictionary, that includes the type of word (i.e.: adjective, past tense, etc.) in some sort of database format, either SQL or something that could be easily parsed and turned into sql.

Any idea where I could find such a thing?

Comment: Random question: Are you going to use this for hacking? It would be cool. Is it bad this is the first thing that comes to my mind when I see the word dictionary being using in a program?

Comment: Just by the by, the garmmarian's technical term for what you're calling "type of word" is "part of speech" (in English, at least).

Comment: Thanks, will keep in mind. I was sure there was another, better term for it.

Comment: @Kredns I am very late the question but personally I would use such a dataset to learn and practice SQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Im a 11 years late on this, but here is a link to a CSV containing the info you want. As well as a python script that will generate the that data dynamically.

https://github.com/benjihillard/English-Dictionary-Database

Comment: Project doesn't cite the source of the words, but based on the count of words it's likely the same as the SQL link above (a 1913 dictionary missing many important modern words).

Answer (score 11):

OSX has a built-in wordlist similar to the ones linked. It is strictly a word list, it does not contain the part of speech or definition.

On Mountain Lion, try:

```
cat /usr/share/dict/words
```

There are ~235k entries in there, so it may be over-inclusive.

Comment: I used [Base](http://menial.co.uk/base/) to import the OS X word list into an SQLite database.

Answer (score 6):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlenglishdictionary/

I've been using this satisfactorily.

It has source code as well.

The database is made from a plain test English dictionary which is not too wordy and concise so easy to deal with.

This is the the plain test English dictionary.

http://www.mso.anu.edu.au/~ralph/OPTED/

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/mysqlenglishdictionary/code/ci/master/tree/dictionaryStudyTool.sql

Answer (score 4):

Some sort of [wordlist](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 4):

[Dictionaries for download](http://www.dicts.info/uddl.php) or
[This one](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/)

Comment: the "This one" looks quite good, though do excuse, I was looking for something that specifies the type of word (i.e. adjective).

Comment: did you find it ?