# Need dictionary database

Tags: database, data-structures, dictionary, trie

I am planning to work in TRIE data structure for which I need a dictionary database or a text or word file containing the entire list of english words. It doesnt matter if the size is huge. Larger the better.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255731/english-dictionary-sql-dump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a Unix or Unix-like system, check `/usr/share/dict/words` ([Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_(Unix))).

Comment: Nice.. This is what (words.txt) is exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: I think that this is a mirror of the file: http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~hfugal/cs167/labs/words.txt

Answer (score 1):

try something from here: http://www.net-comber.com/wordurls.html
or here: http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Check the OpenOffice dictionaries: http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Dictionaries