# is there an api for word meaning or dicitonary?

Tags: php

I have an app that checks the spelling entered by the user. What i am trying to do is when user corrects there spelling it shows them the complete meaning of the word. Is there any free api i can use to do this? With no limitations?

Also i tried finding a dictionary with meaning that i can upload to my server which will have over 200k words and all the meanings in it. But i am unable to find any. Have anyone here used a dictionary like this that you can refer me to?

I looked at this:

[English dictionary SQL dump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255731/english-dictionary-sql-dump)
but these also dont have meanings with them

Comment: Absolutely *no* limitations? That's going to be hard to find.

Comment: *"corrects their spelling"* or *"corrects them there spelling"*! Sorry, couldn't resist, with this topic... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about exporting the data from Wiktionary? You could write a script to automatically export the entries you need (maybe based on some wordlist). See http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Special:Export

Comment: @Laurent- Can you please explain more i am new to this. Its not making sense to me how can i do this from the link you provided?

Comment: Normally, you can simply put the words that you need in the big text box and that will export the definitions as an XML file. Since you want 200k words, you might have to script it though. You can do that with cURL PHP for example. Just POST the data to http://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Export&action=submit